# Align Text in ggplot Stacked Barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I get the labels to be vertically centred within each section of each bar?

Here is my code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(A, fill=reorder(Y, desc(Y)))) + 
  geom_bar(position='fill') + 
  #geom_text(aes(label=scales::percent(5*round((..count..)/sum(..count..),2))), stat='count', position='stack') + 
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(15*(..count..)/sum(..count..)),
                y= 15*((..count..)/sum(..count..))), stat="count",
            vjust = 0) + 
  labs(x="A", y="Stacked Percentage", fill="Y") + 
  facet_wrap(~B, nrow=1) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Here is an example of my data:

```
   A     W          I     Y          Y2    B    
   <fct> <fct>      <fct> <fct>      <fct> <fct>
 1 A1    ELAQY4349B 4905  Weakly Yes Yes   B1   
 2 A2    ELAQY4349B 4905  Weakly No  No    B1   
 3 A3    ELAQY4349B 4905  No         No    B1   
 4 A4    ELAQY4349B 4905  No         No    B1   
 5 A5    ELAQY4349B 4905  Yes        Yes   B1   
 6 A1    ELAQY4349B 3642  Yes        Yes   B1   
 7 A2    ELAQY4349B 3642  Weakly No  No    B1   
 8 A3    ELAQY4349B 3642  Weakly Yes Yes   B1   
 9 A4    ELAQY4349B 3642  Weakly Yes Yes   B1   
10 A5    ELAQY4349B 3642  Yes        Yes   B1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. Sub the `geom_text`

```
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(15*(..count..)/sum(..count..)),
            y= 15*((..count..)/sum(..count..))), stat="count",
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
```